# Difference between adding <![CDATA[ in page source v/s dynamically using javascript

Tags: html, seo, xhtml, cdata

Is there a difference between --

```
<![CDATA[
// content of your Javascript goes here
]]>
```

1. Adding it as part of html response from server v/s
2. Adding it dynamically after page load using a javascript (lets say $('body').append(/*CDATA_goes_here*/))

Main question here is whether CDATA needs to be available as part of page source or not?

Comment: Expressing webpages in XML is more trouble than it is worth in 99.99%+ of cases… so forget about using CDATA flags and just write HTML instead of XHTML.

Comment: Dynamically adding it **how**? There are a number of techniques you could use and they probably have different effects.

Comment: Are you looking for differences specific to CDATA blocks? Or just CDATA blocks within JavaScript? Or do you actually mean JavaScript rather than CDATA?

Comment: The [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." but your question is very hypothetical. What makes you think there might be a difference? What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: @Quentin: dynamically lets say by using a jQuery('body').append(/*CDATA_GOES_HERE*/)

Comment: Try giving a *real* example. `jQuery.append(/*CDATA_GOES_HERE*/)` isn't going to work because you have to call `append` on a jQuery instance not the main jQuery function. The element you apply it to might be relevant too.

Comment: currently I do not know if CDATA is used by any search engines for SEO.. or for any other purpose.. because if I add it dynamically using javascript.. then it will not be available in page source...

Comment: Why would CDATA be used for SEO?! It's just a way of marking content so that HTML special characters are treated as literals instead of special characters.

Comment: @Quentin: if I know why I would not be asking question :)  this is something I want to know.. and if there is any difference in these 2 approaches..

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. It's extremely vague. You need to be more specific (and practical).

Comment: ok updating with more details.. I know its not a yes/no question

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the general issues with adding content using JS, CDATA doesn't make any difference.

It renders in an [XHTML document](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/30828191/index.xhtml) and gets parsed as a comment in an [HTML document](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/30828191/index.html).